# Error compiling for board Arduino Uno SIM7000

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using  **[botletics / SIM7000-LTE-Shield](https://github.com/botletics/SIM7000-LTE-Shield)** with Arduino Uno, I selected all examples but all end up with the same Error

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SIM7000\Adafruit_FONA.cpp: In member function 'boolean Adafruit_FONA::postData(const char*, uint16_t, const char*, const char*, const char*)':
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SIM7000\Adafruit_FONA.cpp:2045:3: error: expected ';' before 'readline'
readline(10000);
^~~~~~~~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

Comment: do you have some old version of the library? there is no postData function  in current Adafruit_FONA.cpp

Comment: There's no "postData" (case sensitive) in any of the files of any of the commits in [the Adafruit repo for that library.](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FONA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned botletics comparatively gigantic repo.  They've modified the Adafruit library without changing the name.

The problem appears to be that you are working out of the current master branch.  Switch to the latest tag, 1.1.0, and the SMS_Response example will compile just fine.  I didn't try all of the others.

[Direct link to the zip file for the 1.1.0 tag.](https://codeload.github.com/botletics/SIM7000-LTE-Shield/zip/1.1.0)